# Tridion Custom metadata for datetime mandatory field is updating as null during siteedit

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t, broker, metadata

I have an article schema which have two metadata fields-

```
 1. Published_date |      field type - Datetime (mandatory)
 2. tags           |      field type - Text
```

whenever content editor edit/update the metadata field "tags" of the component in experience manager, After finish editing component's published_date metadata fields gets updated to "NULL" as the value.  See the below picture

[image: TridionBrokerQueryValue]

But when we cross verify with Tridion Broker DB, we came to know that component presentation still holds the value for published_date meta data field.

[image: Component Presentation content]

This behavior is currently occurring in experience manager with chrome browser only. In Internet explorer it works fine.

- If we publish the component from the CMS it's works fine only problem with XPM mode.
- Why it should update the value which is not edited at all?
- Is there any such issues with chrome for XPM ?
- Does this problem depends on any configuration changes ? such as cd_storage or some other config files ?
- We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 and DD4T for front end framework, Do I need to update or hot fix available for fix ?

Comment: Did you raise a ticket with Support?
Since it is working with IE, there is a high probability that it is a bug

Comment: yes, I have raised today and waiting from reply.